# Jest erroring on the import statement of a dependency (Lodash)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs

I'm testing a component (Foo) that contains a globally registered component (MyTable) which extends Bootstrap-Vue's Table component (bTable).

bTable contains a dependency:

import startCase from 'lodash.startcase';

When I try to run my test, I receive an error that states "startCase" is an unexpected identifier. This is my test:

```
const localVue = createLocalVue('MyTable', MyTable);
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('my component', () => {
    it('test test', () => {
        const component = mount(MyComponent, {
            localVue,
            propsData: {
                prop1,
                prop2,
            },
        });

        expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

This is the jest setup in Package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-vue-preprocessor",
        "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue"
    ]
}
```

Having googled around, I've tried adding this in to no avail:

```
    // "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    //     "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!lodash/)"
    // ],
```

What do I need to do to get the test to register or ignore the dependency?